# WPF command/click argument

Tags: .net, wpf

So I have a background in ASP.NET where a button could have a click handler or a command handler and then a command argument.

That pattern was great for when you had a bunch of buttons that basically needed to execute the same block of code with only a slightly different argument.

Is there a collary in WPF?

From what I've seen of the Command in WPF is that it revolves around an action that is independent of the control that invokes it (and still doesn't provide a way to provide an argument). Which is not really what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you found the [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command(v=VS.100).aspx) property, but not the [CommandParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter(v=VS.100).aspx) property?

Here is a tutorial for [CommandBindings](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands) via RoutedEvents. Using this method you can get access to the control that raised the event, the parameter, etc.

Or if using a custom implementation of [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute(v=VS.100).aspx), the parameter is passed into the Execute method.